# "ValueError: could not convert string to float" with Python ggplot library when making scatter plot

Tags: python, ggplot2, visualization

Below is a pandas dataframe called 'grouped'. I want to make a scatter plot with Dayn on the X and ENTRIESn_hourly on the Y. I can make a bar chart no problem, but when I try to make a scatter plot I get this error: ValueError: could not convert string to float: Fri.

```
  Dayn  rain  ENTRIESn_hourly
0   Fri     0      1336.012020
1   Fri     1      1327.224794
2   Mon     0      1195.493274
etc.
```

**Code**

```
plot = ggplot(grouped, aes('Dayn','ENTRIESn_hourly')) + \
       geom_point() + \
       ggtitle("Entries per day") + \
       xlab("Day of week") + \
       ylab("Average entries (millions)")
return plot
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scatters are good for comparing two numerics, but you're trying to pass a string (Dayn) and a numeric.  Bar chart or line chart might be better options in this scenario

Comment: How can I do `geom_line()` with an ordinal categorical variable, just like implemented in `ggplot2` in `R`?

Answer (score 0):

The error is clear:

```
aes('Dayn','ENTRIESn_hourly'))
```

Dayn is of type string, ENTRIESn_hourly is of type float. The implementation of scatter of ggplot expects 2 floats for a scatter diagram (else it would not show this error). That's not the case for a bar chart. Scatter is used for comparing two values.

Answer (score 0):

As has been stated, scatter plots expect `float` data for both `x` and `y`. One way to get around this, but still maintain a "scatter" like plot is to format a line chart to look similar to a scatter plot using `pyplot` in `matplotlib`.

For example something like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,2,3,4], [1,4,9,16], 'ro')
plt.axis([0, 6, 0, 20])
plt.show()
```

The `'ro'` describes the style of the data points which in this case are red dots. So there you have a line chart that resembles to a certain degree a scatter plot. Above code produces the following chart:

[image]

In your case you might want something similar to:

```
plt.plot(your_dataframe['Dayn'], your_dataframe['ENTRIESn_hourly'], 'ro')
```